# Shortcut to Bottom border in Numbers

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, numbers, shortcut-menu

Here there are many shortcuts for Numbers https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23737?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US.

I would like to have one for Borrom border. I tried (without success) the following:
[image]
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom shortcuts only work if there is a menu item that matches the command.  As there is no **Border bottom** menu command, this may not be possible.

Borders can be of any style and weight, so even if it were possible, it seems that such a shortcut would format the bottom border that was last copied.

A work around would be to format a cell with the bottom border of your choice, then copy the formatting only.  **Format > Copy Style** or <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Then use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste the style to a newly selected cell.

**DEMO:**

[image]

Note that your custom key combination as pictured in the question conflicts with the built in shortcut for Paste Style.

[image: Paste Style]